# Inno Setup: How can I suppress files-in-use dialog when install silently?

Tags: inno-setup

When I run a installer(created by Inno Setup) silently by using `/verysilent` argument and there is a target file being used by another process, Inno Setup pops up files-in-use dialog saying that

```
An error occurred while trying to replace the existing file: DeleteFile failed; code 5. Access denied.

Click Retry to try again, Ignore to skip this file(not recommended), or Abort to cancel installation
```

I want to suppress this dialog and choose `Ignore` button automatically so that remaining setup process can be completed whenever after a user rebooted his computer.

By using `/suppressmsgboxes` argument one can suppress files-in-use dialog but, it chooses Abort automatically so that the installer terminates.

Comment: Are you using `restartreplace` flag for your `[Files]` entries ? Or how your entries look like ? Could you include it along with the exact message box text (so even others with the same problem could find your question) into your question, please ?

Comment: Thanks. Adding `restartreplace` flag to each file entry with `/nocloseapplications /norestart` runtime arguments seems to do the trick.